# If $a$ is an eigenvalue for $A$ and $b$ is an eigenvalue for $B$, what is an eigenvalue for $AB$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let both $A$ and $B$ be two $n \times n$ matrices such that $a$ is an eigenvalue for $A$ and $b$ is an eigenvalue for $B$. How can I show that $ab$ is an eigenvalue for $AB$?

I began my solution by stating:
$$Av = av$$ $$Bw = bw$$ $$\implies ABvw = abvw$$ $$\implies ABvw = abvw$$

But I'm not sure what my last step should be to complete the proof. Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ab$ need not to be an eigenvalue of $AB$ in general, except the case, when the eigenvectors of $a,b$ are same.

If eigenvector of $a,b$ be same , $v$, namely.

Then , $ABv=A(Bv)=A(bv)=b(Av)=b(av)=abv$.

For counter example whenever it doesn't happen,

Take , $A=
\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$,
$B=\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & -1 \\
    -1 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$
Now, $1$ is an eigenvalue of both $A$ and $B$, but $AB$ has the only eigenvalue $-1$.